# Como usar um plugin do Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova

Como usar *plugins* no Cordova? [Cordova plugin background mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode)

Eu já instalei com o comando

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git` porém ao tentar usar usando `cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable()` e `cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function() { ..algo.. };
```

Nada acontece.

```js
var app = {
 link  : "http://images.terra.com/2015/05/20/corinthians.png",
 sCLoad: document.getElementById("corinthians"),
 ativo : false,
 loop  : null,
 rodarApp : function () {
  var self = this;
  this.loop = setInterval(function(){
   if (self.ativo)
    self.sCLoad.src = self.link;
  }, 1000);
 },
 ativarDesativar : function () {
  this.ativo = this.ativo ? false : true;
 }
};
document.addEventListener("deviceready", app.rodarApp,  false);
```

Comment: Poderias especificar qual a plataforma que estás a usar (cordova, phonegap ou phonegap build)? Como estás a compilar a tua aplicação?

Comment: `Cordova` | compilo usando o comando : `cordova build android`

Comment: Antes de compilar, se ainda não fizeste, experimenta os seguintes comandos: "cordova platform remove android" e "cordova platform add android".

Comment: Consegui desinstalei o plugin fiz o que você disse e instalei de novo o plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema é comum, também me deparei com ele quando comecei a utilizar o cordova/phonegap para termos a certeza que as atualizações dos plugins instalados tomem efeito devemos de introduzir:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

Antes de compilar o código:

```
cordova build android
```

Creio que podemos ver uma resposta semelhante em:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538047/phonegap-build-doesnt-update-the-app